# Why doesn't setFocus() work here?

Tags: qt4, focus

I have a QTabWidget inside a QMainWindow. In the first tabWidget, I have a QLineEdit in it.

Now if I call the `setFocus()` method of the QLineEdit in the constructor of the first tabWidget, it wouldn't get focused when the window shows up.

Instead, if I put the same code in the `showEvent()` of the tabWidget, it works.

Why is that?

Comment: Probably because there is not yet a valid HWND in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging through Qt's source code, I found out, that this problem is not specific to `QTabWidget`. It occures, when `QTabWidget::insertTab()` is called, which calls `QStackedWidget::insertWidget()`, which is practically `QStackedLayout::insertWidget()`, which calls `QLayout::addChildWidget()`.

So I added a simple `QWidget` to a MainWindow form and added this code to it's constructor:

```
widget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
widget->layout()->addWidget(new TestWidget(this));
```

and it worked bad too.

Then I noticed, that the following code work fine:

```
widget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
widget->layout()->addWidget(new TestWidget(widget));
```

The only difference between this two pieces of code is wiget's parent.

If you look to `setupUi();` method (with tab widget on form), you'll see, that all tabs are created without parents there. In `void QLayout::addChildWidget(QWidget *w)` mathod you can see this code:

```
QWidget *mw = parentWidget();
QWidget *pw = w->parentWidget();

...

if (!pw && mw)
    w->setParent(mw);
```

Which means, a widget without a parent, will have layout's parent, which is not proper in our case.

Unfortunately, I cannot answer two important questions:

1. Why do layout behave so strange, when adding widget with a bad parent.
2. How can we add tab on tab widget with a proper parent.